# Is there a way to log printk's somewhere from cabbage plugins inside DAWs?

Tags: logging, csound, cabbage

Is there a way to log the printk's from a [Cabbage](https://cabbageaudio.com/) plugin somewhere when it's running inside a DAW? Unlike the classic CsoundVST, with Cabbage you don't get a default log window in the plugin itself, but only in its Cabbage host (the Cabbage "IDE" if you like).

So, when running a Cabbage plugin inside a DAW, is there a simple enough way to get logging from the plugin logging somewhere, e.g. to a file? (I guess I could make a scroll box and write in it, but it seem a bit much work for a simple function).

Answer (score 0):

I feel pretty dumb right now, as there's a Cabbage widget just for this although its name was not 100% obvious when I was scanning the list of widgets... [`csoundoutput`](https://cabbageaudio.com/docs/csound_output/).

> Csoundoutput will display Csound output messages within your instrument`s GUI. This widget can be very useful when working in plugin mode and can be invaluable when it comes to de-slugging Cabbage instruments.

Funnily I found it when I looking for a built-in VU meter widget, which also [exists](https://cabbageaudio.com/docs/meter/), but oddly it doesn't show up n the documentation index on the website at the moment.